# How to avoid a commit/release loop with Maven and CI?

Tags: git, maven, continuous-integration, maven-release-plugin, bamboo

I'm trying to implement the following chain using my (Bamboo) CI server:

```
Code Commit (GIT, Maven Snapshot Version)
|
v
CI Build + Test 
| 
v
CI runs Maven release
```

The problem is that because the Maven release updates the POM to bump the version to the next SNAPSHOT release, the first step of the chain is triggered again.

What are the standard ways of avoiding this?

Comment: Bamboo usually ignores commits from the release plugin: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BAM-10693 - unless you re-configured those messages? So the changes by the maven-release-plugin are ignored by default. Or at least  they should be (they are in my Bamboo)

Comment: Ah thanks, I've come from Jenkins and have only just started using Bamboo. If you'd like to reply to the question with an answer then I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I have run into a similar issue using the sbt-release plugin. Using Bamboo, in your linked repositories, there is an advanced configuration field labeled *Exclude Changesets*. You can input a regular expression so that every commit with a message matching that regexp will not trigger a change.

I have set mine to `(?:Setting version to)[\s]+([0-9\.]+)` to match my version bump messages.